# ArcObjects: Iterate Through Line, Grab points to create a point geometry

Tags: c#, feature-selection, vertices, arcmap, arcobjects

I am using ArcMap 10.1, ArcObjects 10.1 and C#. I am having trouble capturing a line feature, iterating through the vertices of the line and creating a point geometry from its vertices. I am trying to accomplish this via button click.

In detail, I add in a shapfile to ArcMap. I start an Edit Session. Using the Line tool, I draw a line and finish my sketch. Once I either save the edits or finish editing completely, I want to be able to iterate over the points in the line I just drew and use it to create a point geometry for each set of points. The point geometry would  I can pseudocode this, but since I'm pretty new to ArcObjects, I'm having trouble starting and grabbing the line to iterate over the points. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

after you scatch line you can obtain geometry of that feature from *Shape* property as *IPolyline* interface which you can cast to *IPointCollection* and than iterate trough vertices using *EnumVertices* proprty where the point geometry of individual vertices can be obtained